Using tracking and non-tracking submodules at same time in git
Let's assume that I have 2 submodules in a git repo, one is tracking, and the other one is not:
git submodule add https://rep1/repo1.git
git submodule add -b master https://rep2/repo2.git

Now, how can I update my git repository to get all the code correctly? If I use this command:
git submodule update

I will not get remote changes for tracking git submodule and if I use this command:
git submodule update --remote 

It will mess up hash of the non-tracking one. I can update it correctly like this:
git submodule update --remote -- ./repo2

But specifying the name of all tracking submodules will be a real pain. Any suggestion to update all tracking and non-tracking ones correctly without manually specifying each one?

I would create a local alias to update all non-tracking submodules:
#alias for non-tracking submodules
git config --local alias.update-non-track-sub 'submodule update --remote -- ./non-track-repo1 ./non-track-repo2 ... ./non-track-repoN'

and a second local alias to update all tracking submodules:
#alias for tracking submodules
git config --local alias.update-track-sub 'submodule update --remote -- ./track-repo1 ./track-repo2 ... ./track-repoN'

Then you just need to launch either or both alias to update the corresponding group of submodules:
#update non-tracking submodules
git update-non-track-sub

#update tracking submodules
git update-track-sub

